# Gradle sync failed: The project is using an unsupported version of the Android Gradle plug-in (0.12.2). The recommended version is 1.5.0

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'm having a trouble with an Android project migrated from Eclipse ADT

My `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
   repositories {
      mavenCentral()
   }
   dependencies {
      classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
   }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
   compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
   compile project(':AndroidImageFiltersLibrary')
   compile project(':zXing-rev2099')
}
android {
   compileSdkVersion 19
   buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'

   sourceSets {
      main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
      }

      instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

      debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
      release.setRoot('build-types/release')
  }
}
```

My `gradle-wrapper.properties`:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.10-all.zip
```

My `project-level-settings`:

[image]

My `Event Log`:

[image]

Can somebody tell me the reason for this Error?

Comment: Your Gradle wrapper is outdated, and your Build-Tools are outdated too.

Answer (score 0):

Change the gradle version.

Use the 2.4 or higher. Edit the `gradle-wrapper.properties` file with:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.4-all.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
   distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.10-all.zip
```

to

```
   distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.8-all.zip
```

You can also change claspath" to:

```
   classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha3'
```

to stay up-to date, but that's not necessary. `1.5.0` or `1.5.1` version is enough

Hope it help